# What kind of software recommendations is this site for?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I don't understand..

- if I ask for a list of software, it is too broad.
- if I ask for the best, it is opinionable
- if I simply ask to detail the feature of one good graphic program it's not the mission of this site

i.e.

> This site is for software recommendations. If you need help with a
>   specific application, this is the wrong place to ask. For many things,
>   you will find a specialized SE site; but even in case there's none, SR
>   still is not the place for this.

Answer: But... I don't need help with this software. I need to know if you would recommend it to me!

i.e.
[Freeware / cheap image editor software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/freeware-cheap-image-editor-software)

> put on hold as too broad by Braiam, danijelc, Robert Cartaino♦ 16 mins
>   ago
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

So we can ask only questions which are not opinionable and have just one or few answers possible? How?

**Make me an example of a question to which the answer is Adobe Photoshop or 3D Studio Max**

Comment: See also: [How to ask and answer software recommendation questions - aka 'The Ground Rules'](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/455/185)

Comment: See also: [My question was closed as too broad, why?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/456/my-question-was-closed-as-too-broad-why)

Comment: See [What is required for a question to contain enough information?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: @Sam How is the rules not able to be useful for finding software like photoshop? I don't understand

Comment: How about [this example](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/open-source-ssh-terminal-client-for-windows-with-tabs-private-key-auth-more)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't need help with this software. I need to know if you would recommend it to me!

*"Can you recommend me product XXX [ for this task ]"* is not the type of question in our scope. You've put the cart in front of the horse<sup>1</sup>. Taking a look at all the other questions around here, it get's pretty clear which questions are "processed" on this site: "What software can you recommend for task X". So basically, your re-phrasing was getting closer to the scope.

I'm not proficient enough in the graphics sector to permit myself a vote (so I neither downvoted, nor voted to close; in the comments you can even see I suggested to keep your question open). What I get from the comments/explanations is that your description would match pretty *any* graphics program. That is, you would need to narrow things down a bit more. If what you've described is the "complete thing": Say so (e.g. "I don't want any more features, but rather prefer a fast and light-weight, minimalist solution").

---

<sup>1</sup> On SE, that's called [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192154): You're trying to discuss what you think is your solution, instead to explain your problem

Comment: Have a look at this question. I did as you are saying. But it's too broad.. I've put many restricting criteria. What should I add more?  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/freeware-cheap-image-editor-software

Please. Show me a question which answer would be Adobe Photoshop or 3D Studio max. You will find it's really hard just for a matter of artificial, innatural, stupid rules.

Comment: "What I get from the comments/explanations is that your description would match pretty any graphics program." - it's absolutely not truth. There are MANY different kinds of graphic programs. Vectorial, Bitmap, for photoretouch, just for seeing images. And if you restrict to Freeware or having a licence under 25$ and to meet the other requirements I challenge every one to make a long list.

Comment: Ask the guys how would they narrow that question. I'm pretty courious. I'd also like to ask them for making sure they know about the specific domain.

Comment: To your first comment: see the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph in my answer. 2nd comment: your criteria match all of them, except maybe for the first two (where #2 is not clear); "vector" is put just as "optional". "Stitch" is open to interpretation (could be simple "glueing", pasting two sources and save as new image, like "modern art". Make that e.g. panorama-stitch (if you mean that), and you again narrowed it down a bit). As it stands now, a possible answer would be "use MS Paint, comes with your OS".

Comment: Would upvote this answer more then once if I could

Answer (score 2):

**A question should be written, as if you expect there to be one and exactly one answer.**
So you don't ask for the best, and you don't ask for a list. 
*That is my own personal mantra when it comes to asking questions.*

Your awareness of the fact that there many be multiple solutions is given by your Must/Should/Ideally requirements.

---

> Make me an example of a question to which the answer is Adobe
>   Photoshop or 3D Studio Max

Can't be done, any question that whould get both as an answer would be too broad.

A question for wheich the answer is Photoshop would be:

```
I am looking for a photo editting tool,
Must be well known, with a active community
Must have <Insert faverate feature list>
Should work on Windows/OSX
Should be <$1000
```

Comment: I agree with the first sentence, but what follows is going too far. The requirement do not have to be tailored so that there is exactly one answer. They should be specific enough so that there are only a handful of answer. The user story provides a way to rate the answers that match the requirements.

Comment: So this website is useless for finding software like photoshop because our "beautiful" and very useful rules keep this section unusable? And which pro this rules should give to us?

Comment: @Gilles: why is so important that should be only a handful of answer. What's the pro in this?

Comment: Gilles: I agree with you, and may have phrased badly. If you can improve my prasing I'll accept the edit.

Comment: @Oxinabox "Make me an example of a question to which the answer is Adobe Photoshop or 3D Studio Max".  What the author wanted was a question where either of those were acceptable answers.  He's asking for an example questions.  You presumed he wanted a single answer of "Adobe Photoshop or 3D Studio Max" where he actually meant the sample question could result in either answer of "Adobe Photoshop" or "3D Studio Max"

Comment: The root of your misunderstanding was over reliance on the @Revious's written word when clearly he was not a native English speaker.  When you encounter such things, it's best to try to read intent more than just literalness.